# Where to get tenda U10 driver for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I already bought Tenda U10 usb adapter but did not find a drive for it, including on the official Tenda website.
.
Anybody have any idea, where to get it.

Comment: Might be for you: https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=61277

Comment: In `linux` we do not use product names for drivers, but the actual chip identifiers. Please call `sudo lsusb` and paste here the line with your device, like: `Bus 001 Device 001: ID d1b6:0001 Name of that device`, then there is any chance to tell anything.